# Unique URL to EXE file

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I'm developing something like games shop.
There is a dir contents a lot of exe games on the server.
F.e. url to game looks like http://site.com/games/gametitle.exe
I need to protect the url from multiply downloads.
I can include the md5 user's ip into the url http://site.com/games/md5($ip)/gametitle.exe
but how to process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at using `readfile` and `header` to pass the file contents out to the page, and use sessions to track how many times the user has accessed the link.

Answer (score -2):

Make a index.php with:

```
if(!isset($_GET['hash'])) throw new Exception("Missing hash");

if(!isset($_GET['file'])) throw new Exception("Missing filename.");

if(!isset$_GET['hash'] == md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) throw new Exception("Invalid hash");

header('Location: http://domain/files/'. $_GET['file']);
```

Link it like index.php?hash=HASH&file=filetodownload.exe.

Comment: Aside from this being a poor solution, it will *always* redirect to the actual file thanks to a b0rken condition. -1

Comment: This is exactly what the poster wants it to do. You can build several more check if the file exists ect. And as posted above; you can use the header and readfile to modify the headers and force the user to download the file

Comment: @Youri After your edit, it has become syntactically invalid code. This can't possibly work.

Comment: The real URL can be viewed in download manager.

Comment: @user1312750 Of course it "can be viewed"; the client is being redirected. To realize this without redirection, you might want to take a look at [`fpassthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php).